# Django: no module named "django_haystack" but here it is, I think

Tags: django

`pip3 install django-haystack`

... comfortingly says:  `Successfully installed django-haystack-2.8.1`

But then `./manage.py migrate'

... says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django-haystack'`

In my `.virtualenvs/[...]/` I find these directories:

- `django_haystack-2.8.1-py3.6.egg-info`
- `haystack`

... but `pip3 uninstall haystack` says `Skipping haystack as it is not installed.`

... and `pip3 uninstall django-haystack` is ready to delete the directories aforementioned.

Okay, so if `pip3 install` finds it, what's `migrate`s problem?  My `INSTALLED_APPS` hash includes `django-haystack` ...

Answer (score 0):

*Well, lo and behold, I just answered my own question!*

Apparently, although there seem to be two packages, `haystack` and `django-haystack` ... *(and, mind you, this makes **no** sense to me and I fairly plead to be corrected!!)* ... both of them are to appear in `INSTALLED_APPS` as `"haystack"`.

Once I made that correction, everything seemed to work.

*But, good grief!*  Is this really the case?!  Two `pip3` packages with different names that show up as the same?  Will some subsequent responder please clarify this for me? Because my "BOZO Bit" just got flipped.

Comment: And apparently, "yes, it is."